# Create a RAID file server on Linux

Tags: linux, centos, raid, network-shares, redundancy

Originally asked on Server Fault [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/904392), but I was told to move it here.

I have an old PC which I want to use as a file server in my office. I connected two 500GB HDDs and one 300GB HDD to it. Now I want to install an operating system on it and configure RAID so I have fault tolerance.

One thing to note is that the PC is pretty old - it only has 2GB of DDR2 RAM (not sure about the CPU model).

I thought of installing CentOS 7 because of the low system requirements, and using RAID-5. Are those good choices for my setup? And how can I configure RAID-5 on the server?

Edit: Let's assume I get a 3rd 500GB HDD (OS goes on the 300GB drive). How can I set up RAID-5?

Comment: @LukeLR Ping! :) As for your comment, I'm pretty much locked on CentOS, because I already used RHEL for 3 years in my workplace and I still use it today. It's the distro I'm familiar with.

Comment: As @LukeLR pointed out on SF, RAID5 requires at least three disks, so you'll either A) be losing out on 200GB x2, or B) be unable to implement RAID5. Would you consider using the 300GB disk for the OS, and the 2x 500GB disks for data in a mirror / RAID1?

Comment: What is more important to you - capacity or redundancy? Remember also, _**RAID is not a backup**_...

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify that I'm interested in the technical process of creating the software RAID-5 array.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question, I am assuming you do not have a lot of IT experience.  Forgive me if I am wrong.  I will answer this as simply as I can.

Without going into complicated technical details as to why, you cannot do RAID-5 with those diska, as you need three 500 GB drives for RAID-5.  With the two 500 GB disks, you can do RAID-1, which is mirroring.  You need to make a choice, invest a small amount of money into a third 500 GB disk, or lose half your space with mirroring.  Google [RAID levels](https://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2370235,00.asp) to learn more.  Personally, I would install the OS on the 300 GB drive and invest in another drive for RAID-5, as you will keep redundancy and lose less space for the redundancy.

Since this machine is "old" and you appear to lack the knowledge on how to set up RAID, I would stay away from a server OS like CentOS.  Instead, I would go with a more dedicated OS like [OpenMediaVault](https://www.openmediavault.org/).  OMV is a Linux based OS, but is designed to be an easy to use dedicated file server.  It has much of the Linux distro "bloat" removed, so it is lightweight and requires low resources.  I have used OMV and can say it is excellent, stable, and easy to use.  OMV is extremely new user friendly with a simple web interface.  Actually, once you get OMV installed, it is controlled entirely though the web interface.  OMV will walk your through the setup, as well as making the RAID you decide on.

Comment: The first part of @kiltari answer is good, but there is notjing to stop you creating RAID1 using mdadm and software RAID.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll stick to full CentOS because I have a lot of experience with managing virtual RHEL systems (that's the reason I don't know much about RAIDs specifically - I rarely use physical servers and HDDs). See the edit I made - in the case of 3x500GB disks, how can I RAID them?